# Screensaver + lock double login problem after Maverick upgrade

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, gdm, screensaver

Just found something strange after updating from 10.04 to 10.10. I've set up my screensaver to lock the account when activated.

When I log back in, I see my desktop for a second and then the screensaver starts again and I have to re-login. I checked my process list in gnome system monitor, and I have two gnome-screensaver processes(!?), one started as `/usr/bin/gnome-screensaver` and other simply as `gnome-screensaver`. And no, I did not start one manually.

Where do I look for a way to switch off one of those (supposing that's the problem)? I did not find anything in my startup applications.

Comment: Have you restarted your computer since this happened? I had a similar problem that went away after I restarted.

Comment: @DoR: No, but I'll try it. Perhaps it was only a one-time thing.

Comment: Any other options? I have had this issue on 10.04 and still have it after many restarts/shut downs.

Comment: @Andrew: this hasn't occured since; try posting another question, but link to this one and note that this solution didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by DoR, a restart seems to have resolved the issue permanently.